# Issue with Generating Multiple CheckBox in razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2012

I am working on MVC Application ASP.net (c#) 
I have one table of cities called TblCity with this attribute( ID int , Name varchar(50) , IsSelected bit) in my database I am using sql server

i am using method of Entity Framework i have added a data Model in Models Forlder called CityDataModel.edmx that contain my table (TblCity)

to Connect To database i have used in Web.Config the name  ( SaampleDbContext )

and i have added a controller called : cityController

```
public class CityController : Controller
    {
        private SaampleDbContext db = new SaampleDbContext();



        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SaampleDbContext db = new SaampleDbContext();
            return View(db.TblCity);
        }


    }
```

and for displaying the multiple checkbox that exist in table of city i have used this methode :

i have created TblCity.cshtml Razor View : 
like that :

```
@model Mvcentityframwork.Models.TblCity

@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.IsSelected)
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Name)

   @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>(bool)x.IsSelected)

 @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Name)
```

and Index View :

```
@model IEnumerable<Mvcentityframwork.Models.TblCity>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()

}
```

I have 5 cities on my TblCity in database so i want to have 5 checkbox with the name of each city

For example I have 2 rows in my database 1 New York 0 and 2 Sydney 1 I want to have [checkbox1] New York [Checkbox2(checked)] Sydney that's all
The Screenshot  : http://postimg.org/image/h0q2qi87h/

and my probleme is :

http://postimg.org/image/5qz5mch4p/ 
i don't know why i have 1 2 3 4 5 instead of my List of checkbox

Comment: Not clear what your wanting to achieve, but remove `@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.IsSelected)` (your already rendering the required inputs with `CheckBoxFor`) and change the checkbox to `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsSelected)`, and use `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x)` in the main view

Comment: all what i want to achieve is to display checkbox For example I have 2 rows in my database 1 New York 0 and 2 Sydney 1 I will have [checkbox1] New York  [Checkbox2(checked)] Sydney that's all and i have edited my code like what you have told me I replaced @Html.EditorForModel() with @Html.EditorFor(x=>x) but i still have 1 2 3 4 5 instead to have [Checkbox1] the name [checkbox2] the name until 5 ..... I hope that is clear

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor just for posting button i still haven't made it i wil add a button of submit

Comment: Have you viewed the page source to check what the rendered html is. Are you sure `TblCity.cshtml` is in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder?

Comment: When i put TblCity.cshtml in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates he don't find it i don't know why i have 404 error

Comment: There must be some other issue, because its clearly not using your `EditorTemplate`. In the main view, try a `for` loop to render the controls rather than using `EditorFor` (you will need to change the model from `IEnumerable` to `IList`) - e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].IsSelected) .... }`

Comment: so after that  i don't need to use folder EditorTemplate ? just what i have done in first time when i had 1 2 3 4 5 result ?

Comment: and i replace my code with yours

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Did the `for` loop work?. You don't necessarily need to use an `EditorTemplate`, although you can. If its not finding the `EditorTemplate` then there is some other issue.